# rewriting single url help

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm trying to rewrite the following url:

```
index.php?route=checkout/cart
```

to

```
/cart
```

using:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?route=checkout/cart$ /basket [L]
```

However it doesn't seem to work. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: To avoid the obvious: `/cart` or `/basket`?

Answer (score 0):

[`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) does only test the [URL path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax). You need [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to test the query:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=checkout/cart$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /basket [L,R=301]
```

The additional `R=301` flag will cause an external redirect with the status code 301 (permanent redirect) instead of an internal redirect.

And if you want the other way round:

```
RewriteRule ^basket$ index.php?route=checkout/cart [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a redirect so that the new URL get reflected in browser address bar. So, add `R` to the `[L]`.

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?route=checkout/cart$ /basket [R,L]
```

If you'd like that searchbots should ignore the "ugly" URL and/or remove it from the indexes and use the new instead, then send a `301` redirect.

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?route=checkout/cart$ /basket [R=301,L]
```